# Joining 2 SharePoints list in Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-logic-apps, power-automate

I am wondering if anyone has a solution for this issue that I am facing. I have finished building a repeating table solution involving 2 SharePoint lists.

List A - This is the main list where the form is hosted to do all the data entry.

List B - This is the list that handles repeating data. It has a column named Base_ID that contain the matching ID from List A (there could be 10 items in List B that goes with 1 item in List A).

What I am looking to do is, create a flow that will get all the data from both lists and do (what you would do in MySQL) is a left join.

Now I did find https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Using-Flows/Merging-two-datasets-in-Power-Automate/td-p/944323 and https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Join-Two-Datasets-in-Flow/td-p/354458 and I have seen comments regarding performance.

Does anyone here know if there is a faster way to do all of this?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to explain the need to have the data all in one list.

This looks like a parent/child relationship, with multiple records in list B relating to one item in list A. I would just leave this alone.

If you want to build forms with this data, that is no problem with PowerApps. You can build screens that show the parent item and a table of all related items by filtering list B with the ID from the List A item. You can add/remove/edit items from List B in PowerApps easily.

If you want to run reports on the data with Excel and Power BI, pull the two list as separate queries and do a merge (i.e. join) in the Query editor.

That way you can keep the data normalized and avoid duplication of values.

**Edit after comment**: To join the data from the two lists, so you can compose an email notification, you can use the following approach:

```
Use Get Items from list A that require processing
for each item in the list (Outer loop)
   Get items from list B where the ID matches the A item ID
   for each item returned from list B (inner loop)
       write item details into a collection
   next item from list B (end inner loop)
   send notification with item details
next item from list A (end outer loop)
```

This kind of processing is not hard to do and unless you have thousands of records it will not take too long to process.

Comment: Hi there, Thank you for your comment. I have all the forms and such built. Maybe I should have put this in the OP, what I am trying to do is set up a reminder flow (might end up moving this to logic apps if need be) where it would select all the data that is in List B that has a status that is not equal to "closed" and meets a certain date range and then it would generate 1 email per person with an HTML table with the data that is required (including some of that data being in List A). I hope that explains it more clearly. TL;DR - I'm building a reminder system.

Comment: Just to add to my last comment, I have done this before but only for a single SharePoint list: https://tomriha.com/send-one-email-per-user-with-multiple-sharepoint-items-in-power-automate/ so I just need to work out how to connect the 2 lists together.

Comment: Ah. No, it really wasn't clear that you wanted to send notifications. I thought you wanted to combine the data with Power Automate and store it in one list instead of two. I added a conceptual approach for a Power Automate flow to my answer.